# Make Divs lined up without floating?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm in the process of building a timeline feature for my new web app, but I don't know how to get around this CSS issue.  I would like to make "Mauna Key Observatories" in line with "Mauna Key Summit" since that div should not be hitting any of the other trek item divs. I only want them to be listed vertical if the trek_items would cover one another. Do you know of a solution?

You can view my issue at: [Timeline Feature](http://trekeffect.com/trek/time-to-show-me-a-trek/1)

Comment: Vertical or horizontal...??

Comment: Unrelated, but it's "arctic" not "artic" on the left-hand side bar.

Comment: @Maggy May - Thanks.  Good catch... Fixed it.

Comment: @PrasathK - I'd want it to line up horizontally.  It should be on the same horizontal plain.

Comment: @JasonBiondo hope my answer helps

Answer (score 0):

Rather than floating , you can use positioning of the div to place it horizontally .. For example , make the div's position **absolute** and place it at the position using **left**,**top**,**right** and **bottom**

See below code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid; position:absolute; left:0px;"></div>
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid; position:absolute; left:100px;"></div>
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid; position:absolute; left:200px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Working JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjWAA/)

Comment: A question: I always thought that `position: absolute;` takes the element out of the document structure. That's why I only use it to put something "between" or "over" other boxes in my document (like [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)). Hence, I always preferred `float` to `position: absolute;`. What is your thought about that, @Prasath K?

Comment: @Raul Pinto How do you say it takes the element out of the document structure ...?? It doesn't if you position it in a right way and i too prefer float but the questioner doesn't want it to be floated

Comment: As I said, I only used it to position something "over" oder "between" boxes. So, I would say, other boxes are not influenced by it. Hence, it's "out of the document structure". Might be a bad choice of words. Sorry for that. I like your answer and don't have a better answer for OP. I guess, if there's something to add it would be to use `float` :)